# How to Reduce number of parameters using NHibernate Criterion

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am trying to query a PropertyBag Table which contains of 
25 fieldNames 'FieldName1, FieldName2 ... FieldName25' and 
25 FieldValues 'FieldValueString1, FieldValueString2 ... FieldValueString25'

Unfortunatly I am not able to change the design, only the way we query the data.

Right now we query it like this:

```cs
static DetachedCriteria CreateFieldValueBagDetachedCriteria(string field, object value)
{
    ICriterion criterionBag = Expression.Sql("0=1");
    for (int slotNr = 1 ; slotNr <= 25 ; slotNr++) 
    {
        ICriterion valueEqCritBag = Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(string.Format("FieldValueString{0}", slotNr), returnWildCardString( (string)value), MatchMode.Exact);
        ICriterion fieldNameEqCrit = Restrictions.Eq("FieldName" + slotNr, field);
        criterionBag = Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.And(fieldNameEqCrit, valueEqCritBag), criterionBag);
    }
    return criterionBag;
}
```

this will lead to 50 parameters which will all be the same 2 values 25 times.

Is there a way to rewrite this code to reduce the number of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest that i can think of is writing a special projection which shares the parameter. However since the LikeExpression does not take a projection as value we have to write our own too:

```
[Serializable]
public class SharingConstantProjection : SimpleProjection
{
    private readonly TypedValue _typedValue;
    private NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parameter _parameter;

    public SharingConstantProjection(object value)
        : this(value, NHibernateUtil.GuessType(value.GetType()))
    {
    }

    public SharingConstantProjection(object value, IType type)
    {
        _typedValue = new TypedValue(type, value, EntityMode.Poco);
    }

    public override bool IsAggregate
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override SqlString ToGroupSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("not a grouping projection");
    }

    public override bool IsGrouped
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, int position, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
    {
        if (_parameter == null)
            _parameter = criteriaQuery.NewQueryParameter(_typedValue).Single();

        return new SqlString(
            _parameter,
            " as ",
            GetColumnAliases(position, criteria, criteriaQuery)[0]);
    }

    public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        return new IType[] { _typedValue.Type };
    }

    public override TypedValue[] GetTypedValues(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        return new TypedValue[] { _typedValue };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (_typedValue.Value ?? "NULL").ToString();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyInsensitiveLikeExpression : AbstractCriterion
{
    private readonly IProjection _projection;
    private readonly IProjection _value;

    public MyInsensitiveLikeExpression(string propertyName, string value)
        : this(Projections.Property(propertyName), Projections.Constant(value))
    { }

    public MyInsensitiveLikeExpression(string propertyName, IProjection value)
        : this(Projections.Property(propertyName), value)
    { }

    public MyInsensitiveLikeExpression(IProjection projection, IProjection value)
    {
        _projection = projection;
        _value = value;
    }

    #region ICriterion Members

    public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
    {
        SqlString[] columns = CriterionUtil.GetColumnNames(null, _projection, criteriaQuery, criteria, enabledFilters);
        if (columns.Length != 1)
            throw new HibernateException("Like may only be used with single-column properties / projections.");

        var value = SqlStringHelper.RemoveAsAliasesFromSql(_value.ToSqlString(criteria, 0, criteriaQuery, enabledFilters));

        var dialect = criteriaQuery.Factory.Dialect;
        var builder = new SqlStringBuilder(8)
            .Add(dialect.LowercaseFunction)
            .Add(StringHelper.OpenParen)
            .Add(columns[0])
            .Add(StringHelper.ClosedParen)
            .Add(" like ")
            .Add(dialect.LowercaseFunction)
            .Add(StringHelper.OpenParen)
            .Add(value)
            .Add(StringHelper.ClosedParen);

        return builder.ToSqlString();
    }

    public override TypedValue[] GetTypedValues(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        return _value.GetTypedValues(criteria, criteriaQuery);
    }

    public override IProjection[] GetProjections()
    {
        return new IProjection[] { _projection };
    }

    #endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _projection + " like " + _value;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var foo = new SharingConstantProjection("foo");
session.CreateCriteria<User>()
    .Add(new MyInsensitiveLikeExpression(Projections.Property<User>(u => u.Name), foo) || new MyInsensitiveLikeExpression(Projections.Property<User>(u => u.Email), foo))
    .List();
```